# How to animate a rig by using a video as a source?

Tags: animation

I have a series of movements that I want to animate, I have videos of the front and side of these movements and would like to know how to setup Blender to use the footage to create the animations.

I have looked at mocap but the cost is a problem and some of the motions have some subtle details that need to be replicated exactly.

Comment: You could go with a low cost mocap solution using the xbox kinect. The best software to record your movement I know is Brekel Pro Body V2. If you would go this route, the price tag will be about 275 euros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 3D viewport, you can add [background images](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/background_images.html) to use as reference while modelling or animating. You can also add an image to [an empty](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/empties.html) to get an image floating in the viewport that is always visible as you move around. An image sequence or movie can be used as well as a static image.